# Return a table based on switch case in stored procedure using different select statements

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I need to make a selection from Different Tables based on a number.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_Read_Details] @Identifier INT
AS
BEGIN
    CASE @Identifier
            WHEN 1
                THEN (
                        SELECT Name
                        FROM Furniture
                        )
            WHEN 2
                THEN
                    --select Name from Tables with some join and conditions in furniture
            WHEN 3
                THEN
                    --select Name from Chairs with some join and conditions in furniture, TAbles
            END

    RETURN
END;
```

Basically, it's for a ComboBox population based on what the user selects on the front end. First Furniture selected, then, based on furniture, chairs available, then based on furniture and chairs selected, the tables and so on. How can this be achieved in one SP? I know IF ELSE would do the job, but just want to know if there is a switch case or any other alternatives available for the scenario.

Comment: Based on your description, `if` seems like the right construct.

Comment: Adding to @GordonLinoff's comment, CASE in SQL Server is a scalar expression rather than a control flow statement. But you could use it to execute different scalar result subqueries (i.e. single-column, single-row query enclosed in parenthesis) as long as the data types of the returned columns are compatible

Comment: @DaleK - "If you know IF/ELSE works, why are you looking for an alternative solution" - is it not how we become better programmers?

Comment: @Alex - normally something prompts us to think there might be a better way - knowing what that prompt is makes the context of the question clearer. Most improvements would expect to either be clearer to read or perform better - and something would flag to us that it might be possible. IF/ELSE is a fairly basic programming construct which does what it says on the tin and can't really be improved on.

Comment: @DaleK - it is pretty clear IMO, lack of control flow switch statement makes for a much uglier code. The first (the other two) two commenters seem to get it as well.

Comment: @Alex guess thats a matter of opinion - and its fairly easy to google and find out that such constructs aren't available in SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

You can do some thing like below using LEFT JOIN and pick the values based on the `@identifier` value. This will make the query straightforward, instead of `IF ELSE` logic.

```sql
SELECT 
CASE WHEN @identifier = 1 THEN F.Name
     WHEN @identifier = 2 THEN c.Name
     WHEN @identifier = 3 THEN t.Name
     ELSE 'Not Found' END as Names
FROM Furniture AS F
LEFT OUTER JOIN Chairs AS C ON c.parentID = f.Id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Tables AS T ON t.ParentID = c.ID
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried it. Then I realized that for some cases, I may not require 'Chair' table to be joined. It  is based on user selection. I think, If else is the only option here.

Comment: @Cherylaksh, ok. then you can think of `IF ELSE logic`